# NSURLConnection with links relatively to parent?

Tags: ios, url, hyperlink, nsurlconnection, relative-path

For example, I have absolute link:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

and relative link:

```
../../users
```

So the "summary link will be (link1):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/../../users
```

Which refers to the same address as the following one (link2):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users
```

The problem is it seems `NSURLConnection` doesn't understand link1 and understands link2 only. Could you provide the way how to transform link1 -> link2? Ot maybe better solution except of replacing `NSURLConnection` with something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURLConnection just requests a URL, which must be a complete URL, not a URL fragment.  What you need to do is something like this:

```
NSURL *baseURL = ...
NSString *relativePath = @"../../users";
NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:relativePath relativeToURL:baseURL];
```

and then make the request using that URL.  (I *think* that you do need to first make sure the link text isn't an absolute URL, but it might work even in that case.)